# Radio Buttons getting deselected when dragging item using jQuery Sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, radio-button, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the [jQuery UI sortables](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortables) plugin to allow re-ordering of some list items.  Inside each list item, I've got a couple of radio buttons which allow the item to be enabled or disabled.

When the item is dragged, both radio buttons get deselected, which doesn't seem like it should be happening.  Is this correct behavior, and if not, what is the best way to work around this?

Here is a code sample demonstrating this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>jQuery Sortables Problem</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .items
        {
          margin-top: 30px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          padding-left: 25px;
          cursor: move;
        }
        .items li
        {
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: 15px;
          border: 1px solid #666;
          background: #eee;
          width: 400px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
          float: left;
          clear:both;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<ol id="itemlist" class="items"> 
    <li id="1" class="item">
        Item 1
        <input name="status_1" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />enabled
        <input name="status_1" type="radio" value="0" />disabled
    </li> 
    <li id="2" class="item">
        Item 2
        <input name="status_2" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />enabled
        <input name="status_2" type="radio" value="0" />disabled
    </li> 
    <li id="3" class="item">
        Item 3
        <input name="status_3" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />enabled
        <input name="status_3" type="radio" value="0" />disabled
    </li> 
    <li id="4" class="item">
        Item 4
        <input name="status_4" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />enabled
        <input name="status_4" type="radio" value="0" />disabled
    </li> 
</ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#itemlist').sortable();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As soon as a list item is grabbed with the mouse, both the radio buttons get deselected.

If this is a bug, one workaround would be to automatically select the 'enabled' radio button when the item is moved, so any advice on how to achieve this would also be most appreciated.

Update: I've tested this in FireFox 3, Internet Explorer 7, Opera 9.5, and Safari 3.1.2, all on Windows XP x64, and this issue occurs in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but changing

```
$('#itemlist').sortable();
```

to

```
$('#itemlist').sortable({placeholder: ".items li"});
```

keeps the radio button selections.

Comment: Tried in FF3, IE7 and Chrome and works the same. Radio buttons are cleared (FF and chrome) or reseted (IE7)

Comment: It looks like it depends on your version of jquery.ui.  I get the same results as you when I use 1.5.2, but I get just the opposite with 1.6rc2 (radio buttons cleared in FF and chrome using helper and persist using placeholder.)  IE doesn't seem to work either way for me either.

Comment: You are right. With 1.6rc2 the default is to copy the element innerHtml in the placeholder. Setting the placeholder option to any non empty string overrides this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This applies for jQuery.ui 1.5.2. If you are using 1.6rc2 try Ben Koehler solution.

---

It seems that the sortables plugin clones the node being moved. If we clone the nodes using `$('#itemlist li').clone().appendTo("#itemlist");` we'll see a similar behavior, because now there are 4 radio buttons with the same name, instead of two.

You can override the way the sortables plugin works with the helper option. Try this:

```
$('#itemlist').sortable({helper: function(){
    return $("<li>").css({border: "1px solid red", background: "transparent"}).appendTo("#itemlist")[0];
}});
```

We are creating a new node without radio buttons and appending it to the list. This new node will be the one that is animated.
This code works fine in FF3 and Chrome, but IE7 keeps reseting the radio buttons to its default state.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in Internet Explorer? IE is known to lose the selection of checkboxes and radios when copied/moved.

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-299-setattribute-checked-does-not.html

defaultChecked needs to be reset for IE to behave

Answer (score 0):

some sort of answer to radio buttons losing their status is here
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972#comment:4

it's a bit of long way around but only way I could find to re do radio buttons status after being dragged somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of the same problems, but I found a solution here :
http://fiddyp.co.uk/how-to-fix-radio-inputs-losing-focus-when-dragging-a-jquery-ui-sortable-div/  This seems to allow me to drag and drop the table rows, and the radio buttons stay in place correctly.

```
// global script for commentluv premium settings pages
// workaround for bug that causes radio inputs to lose settings when meta box is dragged.
// http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // listen for drag drop of metaboxes , bind mousedown to .hndle so it only fires when starting to drag
    jQuery('.hndle').mousedown(function(){
        // set event listener for mouse up on the content .wrap and wait a tick to give the dragged div time to settle before firing the reclick function
        jQuery('.wrap').mouseup(function(){store_radio(); setTimeout('reclick_radio();',50);});
    })
});
/**
* stores object of all radio buttons that are checked for entire form
*/
function store_radio(){
    var radioshack = {};
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
            radioshack[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = jQuery(this).val();
        }
        jQuery(document).data('radioshack',radioshack);
    });
}
/**
* detect mouseup and restore all radio buttons that were checked
*/
function reclick_radio(){
    // get object of checked radio button names and values
    var radios = jQuery(document).data('radioshack');
    //step thru each object element and trigger a click on it's corresponding radio button
    for(key in radios){
        jQuery('input[name="'+key+'"]').filter('[value="'+radios[key]+'"]').trigger('click');
    }
    // unbind the event listener on .wrap  (prevents clicks on inputs from triggering function)
    jQuery('.wrap').unbind('mouseup');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Randy, the best solution I found was to store the checked property in another attribute and then, after the move return the checked property to the radio input. I did that in a simpler way, using the sortable start and stop parameters, as it follows.

```
// First, create a function to store the properties.

// Store the checked radio properties
    function gravaSelecoes() {
      $("tbody.linhasConf").find("input:radio").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked"))
          $(this).attr("data-checked", "true");
        else
          $(this).attr("data-checked", "false");
      });
    }

// Then, create a function that restore the properties

// Restore the checked radio properties
    function atualizaSelecoes() {
      $("tbody.linhasConf").find("input:radio").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("data-checked") == "true")
          $(this).prop("checked", true);
        else
          $(this).prop("checked", false);
      });
    }

// And when declaring sortables, refer to those functions

    $('tbody.linhasConf').sortable({
      start: gravaSelecoes,
      stop: atualizaSelecoes
    }).disableSelection();
```

Rodrigo